# Produce a Map from an IntStream of keys

Tags: java, dictionary, functional-programming, java-stream

I know I can initialize a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html), and then fill it using a stream. For example, here I use an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) of random numbers to populate the key of the predefined map.

```
int initialCapacity = 3; 
Map < Integer, UUID > map = new HashMap <>( initialCapacity );
IntStream numbers = ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints( initialCapacity );
numbers.forEach( number -> map.put( number , UUID.randomUUID() ) );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "map = " + map );
```

> map = {-14054365=ee739423-1200-45e6-80da-d167ce2e2b98, -1079671217=ba0096fe-b32f-4ebf-a163-114fcb679992, -404094411=f900052b-8a8d-4e66-b808-618fbc7e115f}

➥ I wonder if there is a way to have the stream produce the `Map` object, rather than filling a pre-existing map.

I do not care about if this is a wise approach or not. I am just curious about the syntax and how to use a [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html).

I know about the [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)) methods. But I cannot seem to get the syntax or semantics done properly. I am guessing that `Function.identity()` is the right way to use each number produced by our `IntStream` as the key. Then I tried `UUID.randomUUID()` or `p -> UUID.randomUUID()` to generate the value for each map entry.

```
int initialCapacity = 3;
Map < Integer, UUID > map =
        ThreadLocalRandom
                .current()                              // Returns a random number generator.
                .ints( initialCapacity )                // Returns an `IntStream`. 
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(
                                Function.identity() ,   // Generate map key (?)
                                x -> UUID.randomUUID()  // Generate map value (?)
                        )
                );
```

But I get an error in the IDE saying:

> Expected 3 arguments but found 1

I found examples of `Collectors.toMap` with two arguments, one for the key, and one for the value, to produce each map entry. So I do not see why the insistence on a third argument to the method call.

Comment: @AndyTurner Bingo! That worked. Care to make an Answer of that for me to accept. Or perhaps mine is a duplicate Question to be closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IntStream` only has [one `collect` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-), which takes 3 parameters. I suspect you are looking for the [1-parameter overload in `Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-).

Understand that `IntStream` produces a stream of primitive `int` numbers, not `Integer` objects.

Calling `.boxed()` invokes [auto-boxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_(object-oriented_programming)#Boxing) (see [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)) to wrap each primitive `int` as an `Integer` object. This makes a `Stream<Integer>` rather than `IntStream`.

```
Map < Integer, UUID > map =
    ThreadLocalRandom
            .current()
            .ints( initialCapacity )
            .boxed()                                // Add this call
            .collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                            Function.identity() ,
                            x -> UUID.randomUUID()
                    )
            );
```

Comment: Sorry, what do yout thik about https://stackoverflow.com/q/61844376/811293